# Bind DataTemplate to 'outside' property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I've got a `TabControl` which builds a list of TabItems from it's ItemsSource. Like so:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path =.}">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BlueTabItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=dataName}"/>
            </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</TableControl>
```

As part of the `DataTemplate`, I need to bind to a List found in my XAML Window where the TabControl resides:

```
public partical class SomeWindow : Window {
     public List<string> aList {
         get { return new List<string>(); }
     }
}
```

How can I reference and bind to the aList from within my TabControl's DataTemplate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the RelativeSource of the binding to an Element whose Data Context gives it access to the aList property, then you can set the Binding's Path to aList. So it would look something like this (assuming your window's DataContext gives it access to aList):

```
ItemsSource={Binding Path=aList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) binding with an [`AncestorType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype.aspx) targeting the window.